# Who has the rights to shutdown a Windows machine remotely?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, shutdown, remote, security-policy

The question is about the `shutdown` command with `/m \\MACHINE` switch, which can be used to shut down (reboot, sleep etc.) a Windows machine remotely. In my case I'm dealing with a local home network between Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines. Homegroup is disabled on all machines and networking is managed the "traditional" way by creating user accounts with passwords on all machines.

I read somewhere that in order to execute that command remotely the issuing account should also be registered on the remote recipient machine as a member of `Administrators` group. To test this behavior of `shutdown` command I set up two user accounts named `Test` and `Mike` on the local (issuing) Windows 7 Pro machine. Both accounts belonged to regular `Users` group.

I also went to the remote (recipient) Windows 8 Pro machine called `FILES` and created just one account there named `Mike` as a member of `Users` group.

Now, I logged in as `Test` into my local machine and issued a

```
shutdown /m \\FILES /r /f /t 0
```

command from the command prompt. I immediately received an "Access denied" response. This was expected behavior. So far so good.

Then I logged in as `Mike` into my local machine and issued the same command. To my surprise, the remote machine immediately went into reboot. What gives?

I went to the remote machine and opened its Local Security Policy settings. In its `User Policies` group I found such policies as

```
Force shutdown from a remote system = Administrators
Shut down the system = Administrators, Users
```

I removed `Users` from the latter policy, leaving only `Administrators` there.

I rebooted the remote machine, again logged in as `Mike` into my local machine and issued the same command. The remote machine again compliantly went into reboot.

The amusing detail here is that when `Mike` is logged into `FILES` machine locally, he cannot reboot it, since `Shut down the system` policy is set to `Administrators`, while `Mike` is a mere `User`. But the same `Mike` can successfully reboot `FILES` remotely.

So, what's going on here? How come I am able to reboot the remote machine using a `User` level account? Moreover, the aptly named policy `Force shutdown from a remote system` set to `Administrators` seems to suggest that regular `User` accounts should not be able to do it. Yet it reboots.

What am I missing here? What lets that remote reboot command slip through? What should I block and where to prevent `Mike` from being able to reboot `FILES` machine remotely?

---

A further investigation shows the following entries in the Event Log of `FILES`

```
The process wininit.exe (192.168.1.2) has initiated the restart of computer FILES 
on behalf of user FILES\Administrator for the following reason: No title for this 
reason could be found
 Reason Code: 0x800000ff
 Shutdown Type: restart
 Comment:
```

Such entries correspond to each remote reboot command received by `FILES`. `192.168.1.2` in this case is the IP address of the machine that issued the `shutdown` command. So, as @misha256 correctly suggested, the command is actually executed on the remote machine as if it was issued by `Administrator`. This is why the current policies don't block it.

Now the question is where it managed to elevate from `Mike` to `Administrator`: on the local machine or on the remote machine? And, of course, how and why it happened...

Comment: try the command gpudate /force

Comment: @Richie Frame: Just tried it. Doesn't change anything. Rebooting the remote machine should have updated the policy anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the culprit.

A long while ago user `Mike` (which has been around for a while) wanted to connect to one of the administrative shares on the remote `FILES` machine, say, `\\FILES\C$`. In order to achieve that user `Mike` connected to `FILES` as an `Administrator`, entering remote `Administrator` password and asking Windows to *save his credentials*. The credentials got saved. All the time they were visible in Control Panel's `Credential Manager` applet under `Windows Credentials`.

Apparently, `shutdown` command takes advantage of these stored credentials when it receives an "Access denied" response from the remote machine (or, maybe, it takes advantage of these stored credentials right away, unconditionally). This is how `Mike` was able to elevate himself to `FILES\Administrator` level and successfully reboot the remote machine.

Once I removed the stored credential from `Credential Manager`, `Mike` immediately started to receive the expected "Access denied" response from `shutdown`.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that! This is good to know. Thanks for posting your answer for the benefit of others too :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the login on target machine is valid, it should work no matter if the account type is administrator or user, since standard users do have the right to shutdown or reboot the station. Exception for this is only if the rights have been revoked via security policy.

Comment: Well, firstly, in my case the shutdown rights *have* been revoked via security policy. When logged in locally as `Mike` into the `FILES` machine I *cannot* shut it down locally, since `Shut down the system` policy is set to `Administrators`. Yet, somehow the same `Mike` can shut it down remotely. This makes no sense at all.

Comment: Secondly, local operations and remote operations are typically controlled by Windows security policies *separately*. So, I expect this policy to also be controllable separately. And the `Force shutdown from a remote system` policy seems to be designed for that purpose specifically, as the name suggests. However, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The policies are interlinked and also have some dependencies. This will certainly require further testing. Since this case is interesting, i will try to emulate your situation in virtual environment since I do have the two operating systems already installed.

Comment: @AndreyT This is not a policy issue. Somehow Shutdown is executing as Administrator on the remote machine. Now we need to figure out how that is the case. Hmmm...

Comment: @misha256: Could be. But how?

Comment: @AndreyT I think Shutdown *always* executes as an Administrator on the target machine. Argh, this is frustrating, because I can almost see the answer but it's just not clicking in my head. Sigh!

Comment: @AndreyT Are you 100% sure that, on the REMOTE machine, **Mike** isn't part of the Administrator's group? Because if he is, then that would explain why the remote shutdown works.

Comment: @misha256: Yes, I checked and re-checked it already. Moreover, as I said above, when **Mike** is logged into FILES as a local user, he cannot shut down or reboot it (!), since local policy only allows Administrators to shut it down and **Mike** is not an Administrator.

Comment: @AndreyT Wow, ok... surely you haven't discovered a bug/vulnerability have you?! I might set up a couple virtual machines and investigate. Meanwhile hopefully some guru will come along with a definitive answer.

Comment: @misha256: See my edit in the original post. You were right: as Even Log shows, for some reason the reboot command is executed under `Administrator`.

Comment: @AndreyT Yeah, it's a clue indeed. On my end I'm struggling to replicate your issue. So far I can't shut down a remote PC unless BOTH local and remote machines have the same username/password account with Admin privileges.

Comment: Same behavior tested here. I'll work a little with security policies. Messing even with the guest default-disabled account seems to change a lot of other dependencies.